# Dind in docker-compose connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-in-docker

I am trying connect to docker deamon in docker(dind). I use docker-compose to run dind and docker-client. When I try to connect to dind from docker-client. It gives an error. What might be the solution for that ?

[image]

```
version: '3'
services:
  docker:
    # Starts a Docker daemon at the DNS name "docker"
    # Note:
    #  * This must be called "docker" to line up with the default
    #    TLS certificate name
    #  * DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR defaults to "/certs
    image: docker:dind
    privileged: yes
    volumes:
      - certs:/certs/client
  docker-client:
    # Provides a Docker client container, including the client
    # certs generated by the docker:dind container, above.
    # Notes:
    #  * The name of this container doesn't matter
    #  * The DOCKER_CERT_PATH defaults to /certs/client, the
    #    same path where the docker:dind image generates the
    #    client certificate (and that we've mounted inside this
    #    container).
    # You can execute a shell inside this container by running:
    #   docker-compose exec docker-client sh
    image: docker
    command: sh -c 'while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1000; done'
    environment:
      DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
    volumes:
      - certs:/certs/client
volumes:
  certs:
```

Comment: What's the actual error?  The `docker-client` container doesn't seem to do anything except run a `sleep` loop; is there more code involved that makes a client connection?  Docker-in-Docker can be a pretty complex setup and you almost never need it; what leads to wanting it here?

Comment: I cannot give too much details about project but we need to dynamically run containers in a docker container. I know it is not a good practice but I have been asked to do that. I tried to run docker in dind as well but always fails. So in short, I need to run docker containers in docker. I get connection reset by peer error, how can i solve this in that situation ?

Comment: If you _really_ need to do this, the most common approach is to bind-mount the host's Docker socket `volumes: [/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock]`, install a `docker` binary in your image, and use the host's Docker daemon.  For this you do not need either the `docker` or `docker:dind` images; but, it comes with the ability to root the entire host.